# transferring big files to a limited memory server

Tags: python, nginx, tornado

I want to have my webservice accept large file transfers from customers. To do this, I am planning to use nginx over tornado to take care of limited memory at the server side during file upload. Is this a good plan? Or should I use some other framework/protocol to transfer large file from a user to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tornado needs some work before it can stream very large uploads, see [issue 231](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/231). I'd suggest [Nginx's HttpUpload module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule): Nginx uploads user files into server-side temp files, then notifies your application so you can decide what to do with the file.

Answer (score 0):

F*EX needs only a few MBs of memory on server side, see:
https:/fex.rus.uni-stuttgart.de

You can install it on any UNIX platform and your users just need a webbrowser.

With F*EX you can send/receive files of ANY size.